# Adding 2 text Field values in single textbox in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports, textfield

Displaying 2 Integer values in Single textbox in Jasper Report When i give according to this format it only Shows First value

label

```
<text><![CDATA[Id/Notice_no]]></text>
```

TextValue

```
<textElement>
   <font size="15"/>
   </textElement>
   <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.Integer"><![CDATA[$F{Id}  $F{Notice_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
   </textField>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the class of the expression to `java.lang.String` and then concatenate the fields values to get the output you want. E.g.:

```
<textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{Id} + " / " + $F{Notice_no}]]></textFieldExpression>
```